# Cocos2d -- Check if place is free before moving (all objects)

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocos2d-iphone

Is there a method in Cocos2d like `CGRectIntersectsRect`, except instead of limiting it to one sprite, it checks for ALL objects?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it in a loop. This example is a method for a sprite instance (i.e. the player) to test against an array of other sprites.

```
- (BOOL) checkForCollision
{
    BOOL didCollide = NO;
    CGRect myRect;
    CGRect testRect;

    // assuming anchor point is in the center
    myRect = CGRectMake(self.position.x - self.contentSize.width /2,
                        self.position.y - self.contentSize.height /2,
                        self.contentSize.width,
                        self.contentSize.height);


    for (CCSprite * currSprite in listOfWallSprites) {
        testRect = CGRectMake(currSprite.position.x - currSprite.contentSize.width /2,
                              currSprite.position.y - currSprite.contentSize.height /2,
                              currSprite.contentSize.width,
                              currSprite.contentSize.height);

        if ( CGRectIntersectsRect(myRect, testRect) ) {
            didCollide = YES;
            return didCollide;
        }

    }
    return didCollide;
}
```

Comment: thanks for this answer.  I did try this before you posted it, but it didn't work, it would only return a collision for the first two wall objects for some reason

Comment: if you explain what you did and post some code i might be able to help

Comment: essentially exactly what you did, and in the `init` method I initialized a `for` loop that put about 20 wall objects into the array.

Answer (score 0):

you can set up a method like this

```
CGRect sprite1Rect = CGRectMake(
                               sprite1.position.x - (sprite1.contentSize.width/2), 
                               sprite1.position.y - (sprite1.contentSize.height/2), 
                               sprite1.contentSize.width, 
                               sprite1.contentSize.height);
CGRect somethingRect = CGRectMake(
                             something.position.x - (something.contentSize.width/2), 
                             something.position.y - (something.contentSize.height/2), 
                             something.contentSize.width, 
                             something.contentSize.height);
CGRect something2Rect = CGRectMake(
                             something2.position.x - (something2.contentSize.width/2), 
                             something2.position.y - (something2.contentSize.height/2), 
                             something2.contentSize.width, 
                             something2.contentSize.height);

if (CGRectIntersectsRect(sprite1Rect, somethingRect) || CGRectIntersectsRect(sprite1Rect, something2Rect)) {
    // do something
}
```

or

```
if (CGRectIntersectsRect(sprite1.frame, something.frame) || CGRectIntersectsRect(sprite1Rect, something2Rect)) {
    // do something
}
```

this means that if sprite1 intersects something OR something2 then it will do something

Comment: No I know but I'm dealing with a lot of wall objects, and I don't want to set that up for every single wall sprite, that would be hundreds of `CGRects`

Comment: would every object collided with have the same result?

Comment: for a room saving, but less accurate `something.frame`

Comment: What do you mean by "room saving"?

Comment: like you wouldnt need to add the `CGRectMake` and add it to the code as shown above